# Replacing fragments in 1 activity

Tags: android-fragments, back-stack

I have two fragments, call the fragment A and fragment B

both fragments take up the half screen when shown (this is ok)

the activity is loaded with Fragment A in onCreate being attached (this is ok)

now at some press of a button in fragment A i want to replace fragment A on screen with fragment B (this is done)

however, when i do a backpress, i want to replace fragment B with the original fragment A

here is my code in onCreate to show fragment A

```
    Log.d(TAG, "replacing fragment");
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(resId, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

//no call to backstack intentionally, so that fragment A can't be detached with back press

this is my code on button click to show fragment B

```
            Log.d(TAG, "replacing fragment");
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim);
    ft.replace(resId, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

now when in my onBackPressed method i wrote

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

this is what happens : fragment B gets removed, fragment A does not display behind it. meaning i get a blank white screen with nothing on it, in the place where fragment A was supposed to be.

why does this happen ?